# Alignment in Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left, right-align

I can't find any classes to right align collapse menu of navbar toggle in bootstrap 3. Is there anyway like hooking `css` to do that? Here is the code mention that I need right align menus!
  
      CesaStack
      
      
          
              Toggle navigation

```
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/contact">goto right</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">goto right</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">goto right</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="جست و جو">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </form>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: <li><a class="pull-right" href="/contact">goto right</a></li> add class="pull-right"

Comment: @Zeeba It makes horizontal menus but I need vertical right aligned menus.

Comment: o ok sorry miss-understood your question.

Comment: this might help you a little. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: could you post a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'pull-right' into the class string and let bootstrap arrange the buttons.

For more information you check Helper classes

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

Comment: `<li><a class="pull-right" href="/contact">goto right</a></li>` works but it makes horizontal menus and I need vertical right aligned menus.

Comment: your question was not clear you should provide any example what you are trying to do.  I dont think bootstrap have any class for vertical align you have to use custom css for that.

Answer (score -1):

The collapsible navbar button is `float:right` by default

Simply `float:left` and adjust the margins.

Add this to the bottom of your custom CSS.
NOTE: Don't modify the Bootstrap source.

```
/* floats toggled navbar to the left when screen gets small 
-solution by: http://jonasdev.com
*/
.navbar-toggle
{
margin-left:15px;
float:left;
margin-right:0px;
}
```